# How to make selectize option value editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using [selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) v0.11.0 standalone to manage location values.

I want to edit a selected option value, but it seems not possible.

[image]

```
const $selected_location = $('select[name="location"]').selectize({
    options: [{
        value: '',
        text: 'Select location...'
    },
    {
        value: 'ms_teams',
        text: 'Microsoft Teams'
    }],
    plugins: ['restore_on_backspace'],
    placeholder: 'Select location...',
    allowEmptyOption: true,
    create: true,
    createOnBlur: true,
    onChange: function(value) {
        ...
    }
});
```

As you can see from the image and code, I manually added the location "Calgary AB Canada".

And I want to edit the location without adding new option.

What I tried is that I imported the plugin `restore_on_backspace`.
It makes the selected option editable, but it doesn't still update the actual value, it is just used to filter the options.

If I edit the selected option "Calgary AB Canada" to "Toronto ON Canada" and hit enter, then it should update the selected option value without adding new one.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this link](https://selectize.dev/plugins/2020/01/01/restore-on-backspace) check just apply the plugins: ["restore_on_backspace"], when you initialize the selectize drop down there is the example

```js
$("#input-tags2").selectize({
  plugins: ["restore_on_backspace"],
  delimiter: ",",
  persist: false,
  create: function(input) {
    return {
      value: input,
      text: input,
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Please check link you can edit your values in the

Comment: https://selectize.dev/plugins/2020/01/01/restore-on-backspace/ 
Please Go this Link and check just apply the 
plugins: ["restore_on_backspace"], when you initialize the selectize drop down 
there is the example check out the link

Comment: You can [edit] your post if you find something to improve. You can delete your comments when the become unneded by that.